# Post Increment in C++

Tags: c++, post-increment

I know the concept of post increment but how does it apply to the follow? The output of t is 10. How to explain the undefined behavior?

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int t;
t = a++ * (a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is undefined behavior you have there.